# Convergence of $f(t)= \frac{\exp(it)}{t^a}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Let $$f(t)= \frac{\exp(it)}{t^a}.$$
>
> For what values ​​of $a$ does the integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)dt$ converge?

- For $a>0$ it's clear with an integration by parts

Unfortunately in the case $a<0 $ I was not managed to prove (or not) the convergence.

I tried an IPP, equivalent, domination without success.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: We can split the function into its real and imaginary parts. Consider, for example, $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^a}dx$. When $-a \in \mathbb{N}$, there is an "explicit" primitive. Maybe, when $n \leq -a <n+1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, one can proceed by comparison...

Comment: Please write what you've tried for $a<0$ using integration by parts.

Comment: @Siminore In fact I think I got it with cauchy criterion for improper integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly if $a\leq0$, the integral diverges as $\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\dfrac{\sin t}{t^a}dt$ doesn't go to $0$.
If $a\geq1$ The integral again diverges as $\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{x^a}dx$ diverges.

What remains is $1>a>0$
In this case, split the region into intervals of size $\pi$ Taking the imaginary part, we have,
$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin x}{x^a}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\dfrac{\sin x}{x^a}$$
You can check that this forms an alternating series with decreasing terms. Hence it converges. Similarly, the integral with cos also converges, and hence the whole thing converges.